# Pygame window freezes when I try to run the game

Tags: python, pygame

So I tried adding a random drop in my game that spawns a missile pack which the player can then pick up and it adds one missile to the players inventory, but after creating the '`MissilePack` object and updating my Spawner Class to spawn the missile pack randomly the Pygame window freezes completely and doesn't display any error messages so I have no idea what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
inventory=[]

class MissilePack(games.Sprite):
    speed = 1.7
    image = games.load_image('MissilePack.bmp')
    global inventory

    def __init__(self, x,y = 10):
        """ Initialize a missilepack object. """
        super(MissilePack, self).__init__(image = MissilePack.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,
                                    dy = MissilePack.speed)


    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
        if self.bottom>games.screen.height:
            self.destroy()

    def handle_caughtpack(self):
        inventory.append('missile')
```

and this the part of my Spawner class which will randomly spawn the Missile Pack for the player to pick up.

```
def update(self):
    """ Determine if direction needs to be reversed. """
    if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
        self.dx = -self.dx
    elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
       self.dx = -self.dx

    self.check_drop()
    self.drop_missile()

 def drop_missile(self):
    """Randomely drops a missile pack for the player to use"""
    while True:
        dropmissile = random.randrange(0, 10)
        if dropmissile == 5:
            missilepack = MissilePack(x = self.x)
            games.screen.add(missilepack)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop_missile` contains an endless loop (`while True:`). You need to exit that loop somehow for PyGame to continue.

Comment: I had a feeling it was this, but how would I generate a loop for the missile to randomly spawn without the 'While True:' loop, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: The game calls `update()` some 50 times per second. Isn't that often enough?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry if this seems like a really stupid question it's my first programming language so I'm just trying to iron out the creases before I move onto something else :)

Comment: "He who asks a question will be a fool for five minutes. He who doesn't ask will stay a fool for the rest of his life." - Chinese Proverb